# Matrices in Julia with Orthogonality constraints

Tags: matrix, julia, orthogonal

How do you construct random unitary matrices in Julia

An Orthogonal matrix is defined as $QQ^T=I_n=Q^TQ$ with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. This can be easily found in Julia from Manifolds.jl by the following command:

Q=rand((OrthogonalMatrices(n))).

Likewise, a unitary matrix is defined as $QQ^{*} = I_n = Q^{*} Q$ with * being the complex conjugate transposed. In Manifolds.jl, they have a function called UnitaryMatrices(n). However, when I write the following command:
Q=rand((UnitaryMatrices(n))).

I get the following error message:
"and!(::ManifoldsBase.AbstractManifold, ::Matrix{ComplexF64}) is ambiguous."

Comment: The error message has a simple origin. Random for complex unitary matrices is not yet implemented. If you have an implementation, a PR is very welcome.

Comment: For Unitary matrices `rand` should be included in the next release, hopefully somewhen next week.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find how to avoid the error from the `Manifolds` package, I did find a way to create the matrix you wished with a different package: `RandomMatrices`.

The code looks like this:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, RandomMatrices

julia> const n = 4
4

julia> M = rand(RandomMatrices.Haar(2), n)
4×4 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
 0.0491609+0.547619im    0.337504+0.0588388im   0.107132-0.635825im     -0.252285+0.317691im
   0.37847+0.212615im    0.252793-0.512421im    0.558867+0.412853im    0.00980966+0.0468962im
 -0.257792+0.510858im   -0.327271-0.00628619im   0.10582-0.00169264im    0.742162+0.0584425im
  0.424879+0.0360062im  -0.324348+0.586346im    0.146708+0.262194im    -0.0767287+0.522515im

julia> M * M'
4×4 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
          1.0+0.0im           1.54646e-16-4.51345e-17im  -1.81615e-16-1.63497e-16im  -8.33993e-17+6.35032e-17im
  1.54646e-16+4.51345e-17im           1.0+0.0im          -6.82757e-18+5.95489e-17im  -2.02409e-16-7.38223e-17im
 -1.81615e-16+1.63497e-16im  -6.82757e-18-5.95489e-17im           1.0+0.0im           4.49412e-18+2.613e-16im
 -8.33993e-17-6.35032e-17im  -2.02409e-16+7.38223e-17im   4.49412e-18-2.613e-16im             1.0+0.0im

julia> M * M' ≈ I
true
```

The "magic" parameter 2 to `Haar` is necessary (1 gives an orthogonal matrix). This package may have some installation issues with other packages (at least in the environment I've tested it).

Hope this helps and maybe someone else will figure out how to use `Manifolds` for this.

Comment: You are taking the REAL transpose and not the complex transpose when you are testing. It should be conj(M')*M= I and NOT M*M'=I

Comment: @user21369645 The `'` operator is linked to the `adjoint` function, which does the right thing in this case. It certainly can confuse (and sometimes annoy). See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.adjoint

Comment: Orthogonal matrices satisfy $QQ'=Q'Q=I$, but how about unitary. I suppose you wanted to check $Q'Q=I$ then. Thanks for your explanation btw. Im gonna take a look at it. It sure can confuse someone trying to learn the language.

Comment: A funny sanity check:    A=[3+2im 9+2im; 8+7im 4+6im], B=adjoint(A), A'==B : TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random complex matrix, skew it, then apply the [Cayley Transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Matrix_map).

Here is a Julia one-liner

```
n=5;  C = rand(ComplexF64,n,n);  Q = (I-C+C') / (I+C-C');  Q'Q ≈ I
true
```